# R shiny - Strange issue where perfect app won't deploy

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shiny-server

**Edit**
Solved: Was an issue with the shiny servers which they have now fixed

I have an odd issue where I copy the [user guide](http://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/getting-started.html#deploying-applications) exactly and the sample app won't deploy properly for me. The app works as expected locally but when I deploy to `shinyapps.io` the app only loads the ui and even that is buggy.

The UI:

```
## ui.R

library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
))
```

The server

```
## server.R

library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')

  })

})
```

When I run locally I get as expected:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Za0Ag.png)

However when I deploy I get:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIwcm.png) (notice the input is changed to a text input)

Would appreciate any help

Comment: shinyapp.io servers are having issues today, may be related. Currently, servers are down.

Comment: Yes, thanks it was an issue with the servers